# Is visualization between two fields in different indices possible in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have an elasticsearch cluster with an index consisting of two types.Say X and Y with following fields:

```
X : A, B, C
Y : B, C, D
```

Can a visualization of this kind be possible-"To have a vertical bar chart that shows number of unique A values for each D. i.e. D on x-axis and A on y-axis." This is possible if we have a joined table with fields A, B, C, D.But join operation is not defined in elasticsearch.

Comment: You can try something with scripted fields.

Comment: @Deckard27 Can u explain a bit more about scripited fields?

Comment: Yes. With scripted field you can do new field that are combination of other fields, to do that you only need to do doc['x'].value/doc['y'].value where x and y are values of your index.